# How to retrieve just the final array instance generated with push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm working with [`Underscore`](http://underscorejs.org) and [`Backbone`](http://backbonejs.org). While `fetch`ing my Collection I decided to push each Model's `featured_media` attribute to my `imageId` array. The problem is what I'm seeing inside of my devTools when running `console.log`.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
var images = [];
var SlideModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    defaults: {
        id:'',
        featured_media:'',
        date:'',
        slug: '',
        link:''
    },
    idAttribute: '_id'
});
var SlideCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SlideModel,
    url: 'http://localhost/dev/test.json',
    parse: function(data){
        return data;
    }
});
var slideShow = new SlideCollection();
slideShow.fetch({
    success: function(response){
        _.each(response.models, function(slide){
            new SlideModel({
                id: slide.attributes.id,
                featured_media: slide.attributes.featured_media,
                date: slide.attributes.date,
                slug: slide.attributes.slug,
                link: slide.attributes.link
            });
            var self = this;
            var mediaKey = $.makeArray( slide.attributes.featured_media );
            var mKeys = new Array( _.join( _.values( mediaKey ) ) );
            mKeys = images.push( mKeys );
            arr_keys = _.flattenDeep( images );
            //console.log( mKeys );
            arr_keys = _.map( arr_keys );
            console.log( arr_keys );
        });

    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Here is a screenshot of what `console.log( arr_keys )` returns:
[image]

The array I'm after is the **very last one** at the very bottom. How do I retrieve just that array instead of every previous instance of it?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. My live example is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/DaveyJake/pen/PqNwZX?editors=0010). Cheers!

Comment: Just access it outside of `_.each` loop

Comment: @HarryJoy Oh my goodness! Well I am total dumb@$$! How could I have not realized this? You're the man, Harry! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was courtesy of [Harry Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559070/harry-joy):

```js
_.each(response.models, function(slide){
    new SlideModel({
        id: slide.attributes.id,
        featured_media: slide.attributes.featured_media,
        date: slide.attributes.date,
        slug: slide.attributes.slug,
        link: slide.attributes.link
    });
    var self = this;
    var mediaKey = $.makeArray( slide.attributes.featured_media );
    var mKeys = new Array( _.join( _.values( mediaKey ) ) );
    mKeys = images.push( mKeys );
    arr_keys = _.flattenDeep( images );
    //console.log( mKeys );
    arr_keys = _.map( arr_keys );
});
console.log( arr_keys );
```

I was trying to access the array inside of the `_.each` loop instead of outside of it.